# laravel artisan migrate: when table already exist goes into memory loop

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

I am using laravel 5.1

when i try `$ php artisan migrate:install` first time

I have a mysql database "quickstart" with "migrations" table in it.

When i try second time:

```
$ php artisan migrate:install

(it just hangs)
```

so i tried

```
$ strace php artisan migrate:install
```

i found the following:

```
.
.
.
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 1471228928) = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLIN}])
recvfrom(5, "le 'migrations' already exists", 93, MSG_DONTWAIT, NULL, NULL) = 30
brk(0x2ee0000)                          = 0x2ee0000
mmap(NULL, 401408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe96b647000
mremap(0x7fe96b647000, 401408, 405504, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe96279d000
mremap(0x7fe96279d000, 405504, 409600, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe96b645000
mremap(0x7fe96b645000, 409600, 413696, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe96279b000
mremap(0x7fe96279b000, 413696, 417792, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe96b643000
mremap(0x7fe96b643000, 417792, 421888, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe962799000
mremap(0x7fe962799000, 421888, 425984, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe96b641000
mremap(0x7fe96b641000, 425984, 430080, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe962797000
mremap(0x7fe962797000, 430080, 434176, MREMAP_MAYMOVE) = 0x7fe96b63f000

.
.
.
```

Instead of going into some memory loop and hang why its not showing the message that the table already exists.

Comment: Hi @Santosh Did you manage to find a solution for this issue? I am facing the same issue here.

Comment: disable the debugger

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the migration tables already exist, to solve it quickly, you can delete and create the database again, you can do it from the terminal or a manager like "phpmyadmin". This can not correct your mistake, luck.

Comment: using phpmyadmin, i deleted "quickstart" database. Then i run `php artisan migrate:refresh`. it created all the tables back. then if i try  `php artisan migrate:install` it still hangs showing similar strace output. Why the `migrate` command is hanging if the table already exists

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1 you don't need to use the `install`command.

Just use `php artisan migrate`.

Docs : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations

Comment: what I found is, its not the question of install. Even i do `php artisan migrate` it goes into the memory. It will hang. If i check with strace then it shows like the above Because my migrate command working i cannot proceed ahead